# express-validator custom() method doesn't work. How to debug it?

Tags: node.js, validation, express, express-validator

I'm trying to figure out why this custom validation **always** get ignored.

```js
exports.validateData = [

  // ...Other built-in validations that work...

  body('field')
    .custom((value) => {
      console.log('This message shows up!')
      return false
    })
    .withMessage('Wrong!'),

  // ...Other built-in validations that work...
]
```

I never get the `'Wrong!'` flash message.

My routes file looks like this:

```js
router.post('/person/add',
  personController.validateData, 
  asyncHandler(personController.createPerson)
)
```

**Do you have any idea why this is happening? How can I debug it?**

Please, let me know how I can improve my answer to get your help. :)

Sorry about my poor English.

**Update:** I've just found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/issues/505) about the exact same problem in the `express-validator` official repo. There is no solution yet.